# A Basic Spring 3.1 LDAP Example

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I've been looking for a very basic example of using LDAP authentication in Spring 3.1.   In the docs for the security download I found a page similar to this one

[http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/sample-apps.html](http://3.3%20LDAP%20Sample%20%20The%20LDAP%20sample%20application%20provides%20a%20basic%20configuration%20and%20sets%20up%20both%20a%20namespace%20configuration%20and%20an%20equivalent%20configuration%20using%20traditional%20beans,%20both%20in%20the%20same%20application%20context%20file.%20This%20means%20there%20are%20actually%20two%20identical%20authentication%20providers%20configured%20in%20this%20application.)

> 3.3 LDAP Sample
>
> The LDAP sample application provides a basic configuration and sets up
>   both a namespace configuration and an equivalent configuration using
>   traditional beans, both in the same application context file. This
>   means there are actually two identical authentication providers
>   configured in this application.

Trouble is, it is not there in the distribution or I am having a brain fart.  Can anyone tell where I can find it or another modern Spring LDAP sample?

Thanks in advance

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only in svn. You can find it in this [URL](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-ldap/trunk/). Take a look to /samples/samples-utils/ directory.

Comment: I went into those directories and I didn't see anything I as a newbie could really understand.  I didn't find a web.xml, a *-servlet.xml, or a *-security.xml.   Is there something I need to do to get a set files out of it?

Comment: Well, you can find a Web example in this directory: /trunk/samples/article-spring30/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ Anyway, of course, you need some knowledge.

Comment: That is what I am trying to get.  Thanks for the help in finding the example jddsantaella.

Comment: Other beginners like myself may also find these links to basic LDAP examples useful:
[link](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/tree/9b423a7726e999b6c80e8c4a769a99dd634f56ce/samples/ldap) and
[link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html)

Answer (score 1):

As it says at the start of the Spring Security samples chapter that you refer to:

> To avoid an overly large download, only the "tutorial" and "contacts" samples are included in the distribution zip file. The others can be built directly from the source which you can obtain as described in [the introduction](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#get-source).

So you need to use git to clone the repository and build the samples to get the LDAP authentication sample.

Not that Spring LDAP is a different project from Spring Security. Spring Security uses Spring LDAP for LDAP integration.